# tensorflow datasetsを用いたデータセットのタプルでのロード

Tags: tensorflow, 深層学習

tfds.load()を用いて，food101をロードしたいのですが，その際にタプル指定しても，dictで返されてしまい困っています．

具体的には，以下のコードでロードしています．

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
dataset, info = tfds.load('food101', as_supervised = True, with_info = True)
```

as_supervised = True とすれば，本来ならばdatasetがタプルで返されるはずなのですが，dictとなっており，困っています．

何か詳しい方がいましたら，ご教授頂けると幸いです．

実行環境
・Windows 10 Pro
・Python 3.7.5
・tensorflow 2.0.0
・tensorflow-datasets 1.3.2

参考URL（tfds.loadとfood101の詳細）
・https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load
・https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/food101

Comment: `print(dataset)` として見ると分かるかと思いますが、tuple になっています。`{'test': <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((), ()), ...` `as_supervised = False` にした場合は、`{'test': <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: {label: (), text: ()}, ...` となっていて dict ですね。

Comment: `print(dataset)`としてみましたら，`{'train': <_OptionsDataset shapes: ((None, None, 3), ()), types: (tf.uint8, tf.int64)>}`と表示されます．また，`print(type(dataset))`と入力しても`<class 'dict'>`となってしまいます．`as_supervised = True`と指定しているにもかかわらず，dictになってしまうので，困っています．

Comment: `as_supervised` は dataset の中身(test, train, unsupervised)のそれぞれの shape を決めるためのもので、dataset それ自体は dict 型です。`print(dataset['test'].output_types)` や `print(dataset['train'].output_types)` を実行してみて下さい。`as_supervised` が True の場合は `(tf.string, tf.int64)` で、False の場合は `{'label': tf.int64, 'text': tf.string}` などとなっています。